# What is "pinchfire"?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

In *A Game of Thrones* they mention "pinchfire":

> "Inside the manse, the air was heavy with the scent of spices,
>   pinchfire and sweet lemon and cinnamon. They were escorted across the
>   entry hall, where a mosaic of colored glass depicted the Doom of
>   Valyria. Oil burned in black iron lanterns all along the walls."

What is "pinchfire"?

Comment: Will be interested to see if anyone has an authoritative answer, I couldn't find one.  Suspect it's somethin like a really hot capsicum or cumin that you only use a pinch of :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Pinchfire is one of [several herbs and spices](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Plants) that were seemingly invented by GRRM for his various "Thrones" books to give it an 'other-worldly' feel.

There's a pretty complete list of all plants mentioned in the "A Song of Ice and Fire" series [here](http://www.westeros.org/Citadel/Concordance/Section/13.2./).

The more obviously fictional ones include;

- **Pinchfire**
- **Firepods**
- **Sting-me-not**
- **Daggerleaf**
- **Goldenheart**
- **Sandbeggar**
- **Sourleaf**
- **Spiceflower**
- **Waspwillow**
- **Prickly Ben** &
- **Harpy's Gold**

As far as what it *actually* smells like, it's worth noting that before the advent of deodorant (and toilet paper) herbs and spices were used in great quantities to disguise human smells and to [freshen clothing](http://www.triviumpublishing.com/articles/smellofthemiddleages.html). My personal guess is that pinchfire would be in the same league as cloves or myrrh

Comment: Are the herbs / spices themselves made up or are they just made up names for 'real world' ones ?  Of course, there may be no way to tell.  The name 'pinchfire' suggests something like a hot capsicum or cumin powder.

Comment: I've seen no canon explanation that they're based on real-world herbs and spices. I'm assuming the author must have had *something* in mind when he wrote it but some of the plants like Sourleaf (similar to tobacco except red) and Weirwood (a white-wooded tree with red leaves and sap) are clearly **totally fictitious**

Comment: Agree that author had to have something in mind.  Interesting that you guess pinchfire would be like cloves / myrrh while I guess (based on the name) a hot capsicum. Anyway +1

Comment: I'm basing it on the sorts of herbs and spices that would have been burned in a medieval mansion house but it is, as I've noted, a complete shot-in-the-dark guess. For the record, burning capsicum would result in a sort of teargas that would choke and blind people who came into contact; http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capsaicin#Acute_health_effects

Comment: Sourleaf is probably closer to betel leaf. From GRRM's other books, I know he likes to make compound names for various fictional things - lizard-lion, shadowcat, and yes, pinchfire are pretty typical of GRRM's favored naming conventions. Every writer has their quirks.